# What is the force pair for the normal force? Clarification on Newton's 3rd Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

In the process of trying to wrap my head around Newton's 3rd law I've come across 2 definitive statements.

1. Forces must occur in pairs
2. Forces must act on different bodies

This is confusing to me when applied to the classic box on a flat plane scenario (assuming the flat plane is Earth). I've been taught in school that the present forces are like this:

[image: Box on flat surface 1]

So accordingly I always assumed that the gravitational force of the box and the normal force were pairs. However, after watching a few videos explaining the concept, namely this [one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmmjfbl7zG4), the impression I was left with is that the paired forces are F<sub>BE</sub> and F<sub>EB</sub>.

However, I'm aware that the normal force still exists, but if it can't exist without a paired force, what would be its paired force?

Additionally, can a force be paired with multiple forces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action-reaction **normal** force pairs are: the force the *table exerts on the box*, and the force the *box exerts on the table*.

The force of gravity ${\bf \vec F}_g$ actually comes from the earth. The earth exerts a force of gravity on the box (and table), and the box (and table) exert an equal and opposite force on the earth.

> Additionally, can a force be paired with multiple forces?

A force can be equal to multiple other forces, of course.

However, there are always two Newton force pairs -- the action and reaction.

Note that, in many cases, you won't be considering both forces. E.g., in your box on a table case, if you're only interested in the box, it's rather useless to consider the force the box exerts on the table, the force of gravity the box exerts on the earth, the force of gravity the table exerts on the earth, and the force of gravity the earth exerts on the table. The only relevant forces are those labeled in your diagram.

[image]

Here is a fully labeled FBD, with all forces accounted:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I find that Newton's 3rd law is often written in a way that makes it easy to get confused.

Here's how I like to write it:

> If object A exerts a force on object B, then object B exerts a force on object A that has the same strength but opposite direction.

This makes it clear that you will *never ever* find two forces from a pair acting on the same object. The force of gravity on a ball and the normal force on a ball can't be a Third Law pair because they both on act on the same object, and that's not how Third Law Pair works.

If you want to find the a force's pair partner you need to look at another object!

For example, if you want to know the pair partner of the normal force you have to ask "which object is causing this normal force?" If a book is feeling a normal force from a table, then the pair partner is the force that the book exerts *on the table*.

Answer (score 0):

The reaction to the normal force is the normal force generated **by the box pushing into the table**. The **table** experiences a *downward* normal force *from the box*, just as the box experiences an *upward* normal force *from the table*.