# What happens to the reaction pair?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, free-body-diagram

We know that normal force and gravitational force are not action-reaction pairs but what happens of the reaction force of normal force and $mg$ of Earth?

Comment: The question is really unclear. Can you try again?

Comment: Does this help? https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/637385/256872

Answer (score 1):

The normal force simply does not qualify as a valid action-reaction Newton’s third law pair. A valid action-reaction pair requires that the action force and the reaction force act on different objects.

For example, consider an object sitting on a table.
The table pushing on the object (normal force) while the object (pulled down by gravity) pushing on the table, disqualifies this system as being a third law pair because both forces are acting on the same object.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, action-reaction pairs must act on different objects to qualify as one under Newton's third law.

In this case, the reaction force of the gravitational force $m\vec g$ exerted on us by the earth, is the gravitational force exerted on the earth by our body; And the reaction force of the normal force exerted on us by the surface we're standing on, is the normal force exerted by our body on the surface.

Something you might notice here, is that the reaction pair consists of forces of the same nature; and this is always true, as(you can think of it like this) the same mechanism that is pulling or pushing on you will also pull or push on the body that is exerting that force on you.

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing here to understand is that action reaction pairs act on different bodies.In this case normal force and **mg** act on the same object so they do not qualify as an action reaction pair.